# Javascript Regex - \\d works but not \d

Tags: javascript, regex

So im trying some really basic RegEx out for the first time and i've been told that '`\d`' denotes a digit match.

Please can someone explain why only pattern 1 below with a double back-slash "`\\d`" works when in theory it shouldn't.

After looking in the Javascript Regular Expressions documentation, they also include the rogue back slash when you follow this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_Searching_With_Flags).

```
var str = "123456",
    pattern1 = new RegExp("^\\d{6}$"),
    pattern2 = new RegExp("^\d{6}$");

if(pattern1.test(str)){
    alert('pattern 1 match!'); 
}else{
    alert('pattern 1 no match!'); 
}

if(pattern2.test(str)){
    alert('pattern 2 match!'); 
}else{
    alert('pattern 2 no match!'); 
}
```

Comment: If my answer worked for you, I'd appreciate it if you marked it as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 9):

You do not need to wrap a regular expression in quotes if you lead and end with `/`

`pattern2 = new RegExp(/^\d{6}$/);`

The extra `\` is needed because it escapes the other `\`

Comment: Example: `new RegExp("^\\d{6}$")` prints in console /^\d{6}$/ but
new `RegExp("^\d{6}$")` prints /^d{6}$/

Comment: In other words, when you use a string literal to create a RegExp, that string literal is first evaluated and the result is used. Since the slash is the escape character it is dropped and therefore not passed to the RegExp constructor. So the resulting RegExp is looking for a literal d repeated six times instead of a digit repeated six times.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript the backslash `\` is a special escape character. To represent a backslash in a JavaScript string you must use two `\\`.

See documentation [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Using_special_characters_in_strings)

Comment: I don't know why somebody downvoted this. It answers the question. My answer is simply more comprehensive.